# Laravel: Navigation in 1 blade file

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am currently working on a new project, and for the first time I am using Laravel. I've created several blade files (views) and added the routes of the views. Because there are so many pages I would like to have my Navigation content in one file, called a base file. I extend the base.blade.php file in every view so my navigation is everywhere the same. But, I have now the problem that some links are not valid, and have no route (because they are pointing from different locations). What is the best way to link to other blade files (and views) in one single file? What I have now:

my route

```
Route::get('/jaarhoroscoop', function () {
    return view('jaarhoroscoop');
});
```

my nav file

```
<li>
    <a class="headnavitem" href="jaarhoroscoop">Jaarhoroscoop</a>
</li>
```

So when I am on the index file, it will link me to the view of "jaarhoroscope". But when I am on a page of a different view and in a other directory..

```
Route::get('/chinese-horoscopen/jaarhoroscoop-2016-2017', function () {
    return view('chinese-horoscopen.jaarhoroscoop-2016-2017');
});
```

Like the view above, it will take me to public/chinese-horoscopen/jaarhoroscoop. I cant get it right.. Who can help me out? What I would like is that if I am on above route, I would go to public/jaarhoroscoop instead of public/chinese-horoscopen/jaarhoroscoop.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to have one link (to /jaarhoroscoop) on every page? You could use the {{ url() }} method of Laravel to print your current base URI.  {{ url('/jaarhoroscoop') }}

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your problem. When you are in (root) / and click as an example 'categories' the roote becomes /categories.
When you are in /categories  and click an other navigation link it appends it to the /categories and not in the root.

The solution i give is: 
1. name your routes for easier use across the site

```
Route::get('/jaarhoroscoop', [
    'as'   => 'jaarhoroscoop.show',
    'uses' => 'JaarhoroscoopController@index'
]);
```

2. In your view or your nav view make the links like:

```
<a href="{{ route('jaarhoroscoop.show', ['parameter' =>'value']) }}">Jaarhoroscoop</a>
```

I have added a parameter but you can avoid it in your case.

Edited:

If you don't want to use a controller:

```
Route::get('/jaarhoroscoop', function () {
    return view('jaarhoroscoop');
})->name('jaarhoroscoop.show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel also has a helper function called url which can generate absolute urls instead of using relative urls which tend to create problems like the one faced by you. All you need to do is this (assuming you are using blade for nav file as well)

```
<a class="headnavitem" href="{{ url('jaarhoroscoop') }}">Jaarhoroscoop</a>
```

else for vanilla php file you can do:

```
<a class="headnavitem" href="<?php echo url('jaarhoroscoop') ?>">Jaarhoroscoop</a>
```

This will always generate the output:

```
<a class="headnavitem" href="your_website.com/jaarhoroscoop">Jaarhoroscoop</a>
```